# how to create rspec method which takes object argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am just trying to create a simple rspec method that takes an object as an argument. I can do something like the following:

```
  def check_it(p)
    before { visit p.full_path }
    page.should have_title("sample title")
    p.children.published.each do |pp|
      check_it(pp)
    end
  end
```

so far I have not even figured out where I can put this code to avoid:

```
undefined method `check_it'
```

error, unless I put it with the other rails helpers at which point I get an

```
undefined method `before' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

Some help getting off the ground would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it in various places within the rspec file outside of the example. E.g.:

```
def check_it(p); puts p; end

describe 'foo' do
  def check_it2(p); puts p; end

  context 'bar' do
    def check_it3(p); puts p; end

    it 'does something' do
      check_it 'hello'
      check_it2 'world'
      check_it3 'wide'
    end
  end
end
```

There are also ways to add it outside of the rspec file, e.g. put it in a file in `spec/support` and `include` it into the target rspec file.

Comment: Thanks.  At some point in my career I got in the habit of putting methods at the bottom of the file.  I forgot ruby is like that.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how other people do it but I add a directory to spec and call it support because spec_helper includes this line:

```
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }
```

Meaning anything in the support directory will be included in each run.

So you can just place this specific method directly in a file in spec/support and it will be callable or you can include it in a module and then include that module where you need it.

Comment: Thanks, I see that now.  I was trying to put it in helpers/